# Seam framework, maven-ear-plugin and Jboss as 5.1.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, jboss, seam, maven-ear-plugin

Can someone provide me a working example of pom.xml which is used to build and deploy ear archive on jboss 5.1.0.
In my application I have two modules - web (.war archive) and java (.jar). I'm trying to accoplish the above task using the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>tp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
<artifactId>build</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>project</name>

<repositories>
    ...
</repositories>

<build>

    <finalName>project</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <jbossHome>/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA</jbossHome>
                <hostName>localhost</hostName>
                <serverName>default</serverName>
                <port>8080</port>
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>${basedir}/target/${build.finalName}.ear</fileName>
                </fileNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                <jboss>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>web.war</webModule>
                        <ejbModule>core.jar</ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                    <version>5</version>
                    <loader-repository>com.domain.project:loader=project</loader-repository>
                </jboss>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                    </webModule>
                    <javaModule>
                        <groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
                        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>core.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </javaModule>

                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-el</artifactId>
        <version>1.0_02.CR4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-jpdl</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However I'm getting the following exception
    org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Cannot process metadata

Seems that application.xml or jboss-app.xml aren't generated well... Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems hard (or at least time consuming) to reproduce your project structure and problem. For this reason, my suggestion would be to use the archetype announced in [Getting started with JBoss Seam and Maven in 10 seconds!](http://blog.akquinet.de/2009/09/14/getting-started-with-jboss-seam-and-maven-in-10-seconds/) to create a sample application (with a build that is working as expected) **and to mimic the configuration**.

To bootstrap the project, run the following command:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
        -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.jbosscc \
        -DarchetypeArtifactId=jbosscc-seam-archetype \
        -DarchetypeVersion=1.2 \
        -DarchetypeCatalog=http://seam-archetype.sourceforge.net/jbosscc-seam-archetype/1.2/archetype-catalog.xml 
...
Define value for property 'groupId': : com.domain.project
Define value for property 'artifactId': : seam-demo
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
Define value for property 'package':  com.domain.project: : 
Define value for property 'seamVersion': : 2.2.0.GA
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.domain.project
artifactId: seam-demo
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com.domain.project
seamVersion: 2.2.0.GA
 Y: : 
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
...
```

And `cd` into the `seam-demo` directory, run `mvn install` and both the `application.xml` and the the `jboss-app.xml` will be generated in the ear module.

Then, using the `jboss-maven-plugin` configuration you provided to hard-deploy the ear to a started JBoss worked for me.

Comment: Pascal Thivent thanks.. but the problem is that I have a project structure already implemented by hand... and I can't change it... so I can't use that archetype... thanks anyway

Comment: @Andrew If you re-read my answer carefully, you'll see that I'm suggesting to **mimic** the ear configuration (which is working, unlike yours) you'd get with the archetype, not to replace your existing project structure...

Comment: It worked for me... I've done some project specific changes but generally the answer solved my problem... thanks!